# How to set triggers based on observed values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to using pandas so please point out any best practices that I may have missed in my code. I have written the following python code below which downloads stock ticker data from Yahoo Finance, keeping only the daily adjusted close values for AAPL and MSFT. I then created a new column in the dataframe which contains the daily adjusted close for AAPL divided by the daily adjusted close for MSFT (A), along with another column which is the 100 day moving average of the same calculation (B). The second last column is (A)/(B), and the very last column is the percentage of daily change of the second last column.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Define the instruments to download. We would like to see Apple, and Microsoft
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']

# We would like all available data from 01/01/2000 until 12/31/2016.
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'

# User pandas_reader.data.DataReader to load the desired data. As simple as that.
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start_date, end_date)['Adj Close']

df["AAPL/MSFT"] = df['AAPL']/df['MSFT']
df["100Day-MA APPL/MSFT"] = (df['AAPL']/df['MSFT']).rolling(window=100).mean()
df["AAPL/MSFT / MA"] = df["AAPL/MSFT"]/df["100Day-MA APPL/MSFT"]
df["% change AAPL/MSFT / MA"] = df["AAPL/MSFT / MA"].pct_change()

print(df.tail(9))
```

The output is as follows below. My question is how can I set conditional statements of such look at trends in the daily price and signal a buy/sell based on those signals. An example would be, the last column of the df indicates a % change that has increased for 5 days straight. Or the second last column has increased for 5 days straight but remains below 1. Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

```
                  AAPL       MSFT           ...             AAPL/MSFT / MA  % change AAPL/MSFT / MA
Date                                        ...
2016-12-19  113.490685  61.435783           ...                   0.965480                -0.014949
2016-12-20  113.792313  61.358532           ...                   0.969278                 0.003933
2016-12-21  113.899338  61.358532           ...                   0.970376                 0.001133
2016-12-22  113.150139  61.368191           ...                   0.963949                -0.006623
2016-12-23  113.373917  61.068832           ...                   0.970687                 0.006990
2016-12-27  114.093948  61.107452           ...                   0.976266                 0.005748
2016-12-28  113.607445  60.827412           ...                   0.976658                 0.000401
2016-12-29  113.578247  60.740505           ...                   0.977934                 0.001307
2016-12-30  112.692825  60.006588           ...                   0.982284                 0.004448
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a lot in your question. I will show you how to find consecutive increases.

Starting with a simplified version of your Dataframe:

```
         Date        AAPL       MSFT    change        MA
0  2016-12-19  113.490685  61.435783  0.965480 -0.014949
1  2016-12-20  113.792313  61.358532  0.969278  0.003933
2  2016-12-21  113.899338  61.358532  0.970376  0.001133
3  2016-12-22  113.150139  61.368191  0.963949 -0.006623
4  2016-12-23  113.373917  61.068832  0.970687  0.006990
5  2016-12-27  114.093948  61.107452  0.976266  0.005748
6  2016-12-28  113.607445  60.827412  0.976658  0.000401
7  2016-12-29  113.578247  60.740505  0.977934  0.001307
8  2016-12-30  112.692825  60.006588  0.982284  0.004448
```

We will ask for whether the `change` column has incremented from the previous day:

```
df['inc'] = df['change'] > df['change'].shift()
```

That leaves us with:

```
         Date        AAPL       MSFT    change        MA    inc
0  2016-12-19  113.490685  61.435783  0.965480 -0.014949  False
1  2016-12-20  113.792313  61.358532  0.969278  0.003933   True
2  2016-12-21  113.899338  61.358532  0.970376  0.001133   True
3  2016-12-22  113.150139  61.368191  0.963949 -0.006623  False
4  2016-12-23  113.373917  61.068832  0.970687  0.006990   True
5  2016-12-27  114.093948  61.107452  0.976266  0.005748   True
6  2016-12-28  113.607445  60.827412  0.976658  0.000401   True
7  2016-12-29  113.578247  60.740505  0.977934  0.001307   True
8  2016-12-30  112.692825  60.006588  0.982284  0.004448   True
```

Then we ask for the smallest value over a trailing 5-day window; that value will be `True` if and only if all 5 days were `True`:

```
df['inc5'] = df['inc'].rolling(5).min().fillna(0).astype('bool')
```

And thus we have:

```
         Date        AAPL       MSFT    change        MA    inc   inc5
0  2016-12-19  113.490685  61.435783  0.965480 -0.014949  False  False
1  2016-12-20  113.792313  61.358532  0.969278  0.003933   True  False
2  2016-12-21  113.899338  61.358532  0.970376  0.001133   True  False
3  2016-12-22  113.150139  61.368191  0.963949 -0.006623  False  False
4  2016-12-23  113.373917  61.068832  0.970687  0.006990   True  False
5  2016-12-27  114.093948  61.107452  0.976266  0.005748   True  False
6  2016-12-28  113.607445  60.827412  0.976658  0.000401   True  False
7  2016-12-29  113.578247  60.740505  0.977934  0.001307   True  False
8  2016-12-30  112.692825  60.006588  0.982284  0.004448   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to calculate the difference, then create a column that is one if the difference is greater 0, else 0. Then do a rolling sum on that last column and if you ever get 5, you do something.

```
df['diff'] = df["AAPL/MSFT / MA"].diff()
df.loc[df['diff'] > 0, 'sign'] = 1
df.loc[df['diff'] <= 0, 'sign'] = 0
df['sum'] = df['sign'].rolling(5).sum()
if len(df.loc[df['sum'] == 5, 'sum']) > 0:
    all_your_stocks_are_belong_to_us()
```

This assumes that all consecutive days are present and there are no holes in your timeseries. If that is not the case, you need to use some more trickery.